# Code completion in Vi editor

Tags: editor, vi

Is there an autocomplete feature for Vi? <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> looks for keywords already used in the document. But suppose I want `a.funcname` to automatically show members of object `a`. Is it possible with Vi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)**. It’s a plugin that offers extremely fast, fully syntax-aware auto-completion. It furthermore shows code errors on the fly (by putting a marker inside the margin next to the offending line).

So far, C++, C# and Python are natively supported. However, the plugin has an easily accessible API to add support for more languages.

There are other plugins but with the exception of [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) (for Python only) nothing comes even close to working properly.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at supertab: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643

Answer (score 3):

I realise this isn't quite answering your question, but have you looked at running vi within an IDE ?

[viPlugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/) works with [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and is a pretty good vi emulation. Since it runs within Eclipse you get all the code completion that Eclipse provides. Eclipse isn't just for Java, btw. It works with a variety of languages and may well cater for what you need.

This is the direction I took when I reluctantly realised that vi *by itself* wasn't providing as much help as I needed when developing, but I was reluctant to give up the power of the editor.

Answer (score 2):

I use [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) with the [jVi](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/) plugin. It gives me the editing power of vi with the intelligent auto-completion features of NetBeans.

Comment: netbeans and eclipse are powerful editors themselves. why do you need vi plugins in them.

Comment: Honestly, its a different type of power. IDE's have powerful capabilities, like scanning a project and providing intelligent auto-completion, syntax highlighting, etc. Vi-style editing provides power at a low-level, pure text editing way. With the jVi plugin, you lose none of the underlying power of the IDE, so you get the best of both worlds. It's a win-win. Vi/vim is still *very* popular: http://answers.polldaddy.com/poll/2150554/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your language.  For c++, for example, there is [omnicppcomplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520).